# How to access, in SCSS or CSS, the breakpoints configured using the Drupal breakpoints module

Tags: drupal-7, sass, drupal-modules, breakpoints

Is it possible to use the breakpoints that have been configured via the Drupal Breakpoints module in my scss files? Probably simple but I can't find any way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an npm project (with a Gulp example in the README) which adds the breakpoints to your SCSS: https://github.com/jenslind/drupal-breakpoints-scss

Comment: Oh, sorry. My answer is for Drupal 8 version. Perhaps you could fork the repo and create the Drupal 7 version?